# Is it possible to install Flow on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, flow-project

I am trying to install flow but I am on Windows 10. When reading the installation instruction https://flow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_setup.html#local-installation I feel like it is only possible to do it on a Ubuntu/Mac distribution ...

Do you know if it is possible to install it on Windows 10 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question some weeks ago and came to the conclusion, that is is not possible to install the whole thing on windows. The whole learning part is done with the help of the ray framework, which unfortunately is not available on windows, yet.
I ended up creating an ubuntu partition on my windows laptop, to be able to use it.

BR, Vallout

Comment: Ok, I wanted to avoid that solution ^^ , but I guess I don't have the choice ...  Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I am not an expert but could it possible via docker ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows10 professional. I would suggest you to run flow in  ubuntu virtual machine through hyper-v. It is very convenience other than you are not able to utilise gpu.